# How to use ControllerManager? (from ros_control)

Tags: ros, ros-control, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am looking for an example of how to use controller_manager::ControllerManager. I have read a tutorial on implementing one's own hardware interface ([see here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki/hardware_interface)) and there is a few lines of code (including a **main** function) related to my problem. But unfortunately I do not understand where this **main** function should lie (is it into a specific node?). I am not too sure either how it should articulate with the controller_manager spawner node instantiated in the launch file.

I have checked several repos (like [D. Coleman's baxter](https://github.com/davetcoleman/baxter_cpp/blob/indigo-devel/baxter_control/include/baxter_control/baxter_hardware_interface.h), and the [husky ros files](https://github.com/husky)...) but could not find any code relevant to me.

Is there any example somewhere showing me how to use the ControllerManager in c++?

--- EDIT ---
To put it another way [here it shows](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki/hardware_interface) a main() implementing the logic of the robot read/write and controllers update. But who starts the app corresponding to the main? Is this a node? And external app? Something else?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194737/how-to-use-controllermanager?-(from-ros_control)/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The example quoted in the question is a decent one, as it's possibly the simplest setting. There are a few practical details missing, but it gives a good idea of what needs to be done.

A similar but more complete example  is detailed in the ROSCON 2014 talk entitled ROS control: an overview ([program](http://roscon.ros.org/2014/program/) with slides and video). Here you can see how the `main` function initializes a ros node, which you can then launch via `rosrun`/`roslauch`. Let us know if you still have questions along these lines.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-10-14**:
Ha! I believe your second example is relevant, I will look into deeper. Thanks!

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-10-16**:
Was the example detailed enough to answer your question?. If so, please mark it as such, otherwise the robot-control SIG is the best place to continue a more detailed discussion. Thanks!.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-10-16**:
This is done!